# How sshhould i design the layout of this image recived from designer?

Tags: java, android, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BpzL.jpg)

How should I achive this in xml android studio java, I am a biginner in android developement, edittext looks different than this in material design components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout can simply be achieved by adding the EditText inside the CardView.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The code will give you same results EditText as shown for in the image.

Comment: Thankyou, so the background of edittext white to remove the line under text and wrapped in cardview, thanks for the easy solution